# Problema com vetor de árvore AVL

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hash

Boa tarde!

Estou fazendo uma tabela hash e para isso estou tentando criar um vetor de Árvore AVL. O problema é que quando tento inserir um valor em qualquer arvore desse vetor está dando a exceção "NullPointerException". Alguém poderia me informar onde estou errando?

Fico muito agradecido.

```
public class Hashing {
ArvoreAvl[] lAVL;
int mod;

public Hashing(int tamanho){
    lAVL = new ArvoreAvl[tamanho];
    mod = tamanho;        
}

public void inserir(int valor){
    int rest = valor % mod;
    for(int x = 1; x < lAVL.length; x++){
        if(x == rest){
            // Está dando java.lang.NullPointerException na linha abaixo
            lAVL[x].inserir(valor);
        }
    }
}

public void remover(int valor){
    int rest = valor % mod;

    for(int x = 0; x < mod; x++){
        if(x == rest){
            lAVL[x].remover(valor);
        }
    }
}

public void imprimir(){
   for(int x = 0; x < lAVL.length; x++){
        lAVL[x].inorder();
        System.out.println();
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está esquecendo de instanciar o vetor `lAVL[x]` naquela linha adicione a instancia:

```
if(x == rest){
    lAVL[x] = new ArvoreAvl();
    lAVL[x].inserir(valor);
}
```

No construtor da sua classe, você está definindo o tamanho do seu vetor, mas não está instanciando a classe `ArvoreAVL` para as posições do vetor.
 Mesma coisa que eu fizesse:

```
ClasseQualquer[] classe = new ClasseQualquer[10];
```

Isso apenas definiu o tamanho do meu vetor na classe `ClasseQualquer` então para mim instanciar teria que colocar dentro de um for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    classe[i] = new ClasseQualquer();
}
```

Comment: Mas eu estou fazendo isso no construtor da classe.

Comment: Não não, no construtor da classe você não está instanciando hehe vocÊ tem que instanciar cada nó do seu vetor, vou editar o a resposta ve se consegue entender melhor.

Comment: Ahh, agora consegui entender Matheus. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. :)